# request.get not working // and a more general one

Tags: python, python-requests

new to python (4 months)
got thru the first steps of basic programming skills, I believe, (having passed edX MIT 6001x and 60002x)
having big problems in the world of new libraries...
here an example:

```
r= requests.get ('URL',timeout=x)
```

works well with certain URL, keeps waiting with some other URL and I am getting

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='URL', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=x)
```

and without the timeout parameter, the jupyter notebook keeps turning the sand-watch.

I am not trying to handle the exception but to get it work.
Is there a simple way out or is requests.get too short for these kind of tasks?

And a more general question here,if you have the time: learning from the official docs (especially for larger and more complex modules) is getting too abstract for me, where it makes me feel hopeless. 'Straight diving' produces problems such as this one where you even cant figure out the simplest..
What would be an efficient way to deal with state of the art libraries? How did/do you go forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check a file "robots.txt" of the website whose content you're trying to scrape (just type something like www.example.com/robots.txt). It's plausible that the website simply does not allow robots to use it. If this is the case, you may try to trick it by passing a custom header:

```
import requests
headers={'user-agent':'Chrome/41.0.2228.0'}
url='...'
r=requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=x)
```

But, of course, if you make thousands of queries to a website which does not allow robots, you'll still be blocked after a while.

Comment: thank you, indeed there was a robots.txt file starting with:

Comment: # Crawlers
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Comment: and the headers trick also worked...(I guess I should not press enter to go to the next line while commenting :-)) appreciated